# Checking if a cookie has made it to the client's browser without waiting for the next connection

Tags: php, session-cookies, session-hijacking

I am building a session control library that is designed to implement a (limited) form of security on the session store to prevent session hijacking (without SSL).

It works by setting an nonce cookie, which is changed to a random string on every request. So far, it has worked well, and I have come up with a rudimentary way to keep the session data valid if the connection times out prematurely and the cookie doesn't make it to the client. It does this by keeping the last nonce that was set, and if the old nonce is in place, it won't update it. It is also only valid for a few seconds.

But this does provide a small security hole that could potentially be exploited by a hacker for a short window, and I am trying to plug that hole at the moment.

The best way I can determine so far is to somehow, check that the connection lasted long enough for the cookie to be sent to the client. I have looked at [`connection_handling`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php), but I am unsure if the cookie has been sent over the network (even if the status is `normal` at the time of `setcookie`) or has been accepted by the browser.

So, are there any methods that could confirm if a cookie has been set on the clients browser without having to wait for the client to make another request?

Comment: No. Only the browser sending the cookie data back can confirm that it has the cookie data, anything else is just hoping that it has it

Answer (score 2):

You can't know for sure whether a client has received the cookie until the next request.

Alternatively, you can keep a limited list of nonces, each with their identifier; those two values are sent to the client in a cookie. If one of the cookies didn't make it, the next request will bear the previous identifier and value.

You decide whether the given nonce is recent enough to be used by limiting the number of valid identifiers.

This is pretty similar to what you have, though. SSL would help keeping the session identifier safe, but you would still want to keep a nonce management system in place to prevent replay attacks.

Comment: Yeah, thought I would have to do something along those lines. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of knowing that a browser has received the cookie data, without the browser making a request to confirm that.

You could use javascript to send a confirmation request back to the server and thus expire any previous nonces so only the last one confirmed was valid.

In the event javascript was disabled or the confirmation not received, you would still accept the previous confirmed session.